# install a modified kvm driver requires access to the linux source

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I tried to install [Nitro](https://github.com/pfohjo/nitro) which requires installation of modified KVM (nitro-kmod_build). when I do `make sync` it requires `kvm_host.h` :

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'header/include/linux/kvm_host.h'
```

so I do `make sync` by giving the path to the Linux Kernel headers :

```
make sync LINUX=/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.9-031309
```

but now it needs to see one of the Linux Kernel source file which is `kvm_main.c`:

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'source/kvm_main.c'
```

So how can I tell the program path to this file?

Comment: What distro are you running on?

Comment: 3.13.9-031309-generic x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux